# Showing multiple validation alert on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have written a Jquery code for *validation*. But the problem here is that, First the **regular expression** message fires and after that **requiredField** error message fires.

Here is my code:-

```
var ErrArr = [];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            validateTextBoxes();
            function FunValidatePan()
            if (ErrArr.length > 0)
            {
                alert(ErrArr.join("\n"));
                ErrArr = [];
                return false;
            }
        });
        function validateTextBoxes() {
            if ($("#txtPanNo").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push('Pan No is required');
            }
        }
        function FunValidatePan() {
            var StrPriError = "";
            if (Trim(document.getElementById("txtPanNo").value) != "" && Trim(document.getElementById("txtPanNo").value) != "NULL") {
                var fil = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
                if (fil.test(document.getElementById("txtPanNo").value)) {
                    var abc = Trim(document.getElementById("txtPanNo").value);
                    if (abc.length != 10) {
                        StrPriError += ' Enter valid PAN Card\n';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    StrPriError += ' Enter valid PAN Card\n';
                }
            }
            if (StrPriError != "") {
                alert(StrPriError);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

I want that in single message. How to achieve that. Please suggest. Also I want that in Jquery

**UPDATE**

ASPX

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPanNo" runat="server" Width="100" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Could you post your html?

Comment: @Tomasz: See the update

Comment: you are calling   if (StrPriError != "") {
                alert(StrPriError);
                return false;
            }
it should alert first

Comment: @prashanth: Yes, how should I do that, can you please suggest me

Comment: Where is ErrArr.push for second method. You are using alert in second method instead of just push.

Comment: @prashanth: I haven't used that, please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check changes in the above code.

```
var ErrArr = [];
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                validateTextBoxes();
                FunValidatePan();

                if (ErrArr.length > 0)
                {
                    alert(ErrArr.join("\n"));
                    ErrArr = [];
                    return false;
                }
            });

            function validateTextBoxes() {
                if ($("#txtPanNo").val() === "") {
                    ErrArr.push('Pan No is required');
                }
            }
            function FunValidatePan() {
                if (Trim(document.getElementById("txtPanNo").value) != "" && Trim(document.getElementById("txtPanNo").value) != "NULL") {
                    var fil = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
                    if (fil.test(document.getElementById("txtPanNo").value)) {
                        var abc = Trim(document.getElementById("txtPanNo").value);
                        if (abc.length != 10) {
                            ErrArr.push('Enter valid PAN Card');
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        ErrArr.push('Enter valid PAN Card');
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: After adding your code, my all validation is not firing.

Comment: When I remove the `FunValidatePan` it works but I when I add that function it does not works.